# Google API restrictions referrer error 403

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-data-api

I setup a cron job to execute a php script every x minutes which uses youtubes data api v3 to fetch video viewcounts.

Whenever I execute the script I get a 403 error, same thing shows in google developer console.

If I take off my API key referrer restrictions everything works fine, but thats obviously not an option for security reasons.

Also regenerated a new key, disabled/reenabled the youtube data api v3 in the google developer console, problem still persists.

http referrer list in google developer console API key restrictions:

`*website.com/*`

`*.website.com/*`

`http://website.com/*`

`website.com/*`

`website.com/script.php`

the script:

```
$saveLocation = "./videoStatistics.json";

$apiPath = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics";
$key = "myapikey";

$json = file_get_contents($apiPath."&id=".implode(",", $videos)."&key=".$key);

$data = json_decode($json);

$result = [];

foreach ($data->items as $video) {
    $result[$video->id] = $video->statistics;
}

file_put_contents($saveLocation, json_encode($result));
```

I checked other questions as well but solutions didnt seem to work. The new google developer console seems to have no option to select browser or server based API creation as well if that is even the problem.

Comment: Google API is vague, google has numerous, please specify in your question. What is your cron job doing? Be more specific about your issue. I see you are new. Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the referrer restrictions.

They're intended for situations where the API key is used in client-side code, making it possible for users to see the API key. In these situations, these restrictions prevent the API key from being misused by other web sites.

Since you're using this API key in server-side code, you don't need to worry about this. If you need to use the YouTube API in other client-side code, create a separate API key for that.